# PhoneGap: How to Get list of all plugins using Javascript

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I am trying to retreive list of all available plugins using Javascript in phoneGap.

Is this possible to get list of available plugins?

Any response will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you refer to all plugins included in your project?, only the plugins in your project using javascript? or all the plugins existing in the world?

Comment: @Del I want only availbale plugins which are acceible through javascript in current app environment not in the world.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard, there is no a easy way.

Some plugins store their function in cordova.plugin, you can check this to retrieve some. Others include their functions in the window global variable...

The only real way I know, is to enter into the CLI

```
cordova plugin list
```

Or just check your plugins folder. But this is not in the javascript.

The only way I have in mind right now, is to do a hook, in node, in the before_prepare, which reads the plugin directory, and stores that data somewhere, so you can access it in the javascript.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

**All PhoneGap Plugins:**

As per I understand from your question that you want all the list of PhoneGap plugins which is supported by JavaScript.

Flow the below-mentioned link to find out all the plugins for PhoneGap using javascript.

[PhoneGap Plugin List](http://www.plugreg.com/plugins)

***Hope the answer help's you. Cheers. Happy coding***

Comment: Thanks Dron for response. But I want to extract the list (names) of only available plugins through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Check how cordova.js is registrating the plugins
https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/blob/master/src/common/pluginloader.js

You can then iterate through the `<script>` elements after initialisation is complete and log their src.

From https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/blob/master/src/common/modulemapper.js you might event get their ids.

Answer (score 0):

@user2899728,
your question begs a certain amount of ignorance. Cordova/Phonegap uses only HTML, CSS and Javascript. [FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/) (last question). So, the real question: *where do I get plugins?*

There are several respositories.

- http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/ - The "official" repository.
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugins - npm mirror of "official"
- https://build.phonegap.com/plugins - The "official" phonegap repository. (retired, but readable)
- http://www.plugreg.com/plugins

More plugins are available on github, but they are sources for the "official" or independent that can be used with the "plugin" method. (See [plugman](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html))

NOTE: This exclude libraries that may be available on the Internet, such as [Jquery](http://jquery.com/), or service-based libraries - like [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). -- Best of Luck.